# Can't get tic-tac-toe winner check function to check for diagonals

Tags: kotlin, game-development, tic-tac-toe

Excuse the long title. StackOverflow won't accept a shorter one.

I'm trying to make a Tic-tac-toe android game in Kotlin. So far everything has been working perfectly fine with the exception of the diagonal check.

Basically what the `winnerCheck()` function does is it creates a matrix with all the containers in the tic-tac-toe board, and then it checks the rows, columns and the diagonal of the board for equal values. If the winner is detected, the function sets the `winner` text to "You win". The row and column checking works fine, but if, say, I have 3 X-s on the diagonal, nothing happens.

The code seems fine to me so I have no idea what's wrong.

EDIT: I am aware that I haven't included the condition for the anti-diagonal check, that's because I'm still not finished.

```kotlin
package com.example.mygame

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var view00: TextView
    lateinit var view01: TextView
    lateinit var view02: TextView
    lateinit var view10: TextView
    lateinit var view11: TextView
    lateinit var view12: TextView
    lateinit var view20: TextView
    lateinit var view21: TextView
    lateinit var view22: TextView
    lateinit var winner: TextView


    var playerIndicator = true

    fun createViews() {
        view00 = findViewById(R.id.topleft)
        view01 = findViewById(R.id.topcenter)
        view02 = findViewById(R.id.topright)

        view10 = findViewById(R.id.midleft)
        view11 = findViewById(R.id.midcenter)
        view12 = findViewById(R.id.midright)

        view20 = findViewById(R.id.bottomleft)
        view22 = findViewById(R.id.bottomcenter)
        view21 = findViewById(R.id.bottomright)

        winner = findViewById(R.id.winner)
    }



    fun setListeners() {
        val views = listOf(view00, view01, view02, view10, view11, view12, view20, view22, view21)
        for (view in views) {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                if (playerIndicator == true) {
                    view.setText("X")
                    playerIndicator = false
                    view.setOnClickListener(null)
                    winnerCheck()
                } else {
                    view.setText("O")
                    playerIndicator = true
                    view.setOnClickListener(null)
                    winnerCheck()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        createViews()
        setListeners()
    }

    fun winnerCheck() {
        val board = arrayOf(
            arrayOf(view00, view01, view02),
            arrayOf(view10, view11, view12),
            arrayOf(view20, view21, view22)
        )

        if (board[0][0].text!="" && board[1][1].text==board[0][0].text && board[2][2].text==board[0][0].text) {
            winner.setText("You win")
        } // DIAGONAL CHECK

        for (i in 0 .. 2) {
            if (board[i][0].text!="" && board[i][0].text==board[i][1].text && board[i][2].text==board[i][0].text) {
                winner.setText("You win")
            }
            if (board[0][i].text!="" && board[1][i].text==board[0][i].text && board[0][i].text==board[2][i].text) {
                winner.setText("You win")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant, but your code is working too hard. As soon as it finds a winning combination your winner check should _stop_. There is no point checking any further.

Comment: A tic-tac-toe board has two diagonals. It seems you are only checking one.

Comment: Another issue is that you seem to be checking whether _either_ player has won but then telling the same player that that player has won. In other words, you are finding three in a row but not asking whether it's three X or three O.

Comment: Sorry to rattle on, but I'd also like to point out that there is a fundamental architectural flaw in your entire approach: you are using the `text` of your TextViews as _data_. This is very wrong. You should be storing a knowledge of what the board contains as a pure data structure, and checking _that_. That is called the "model". The visible TextViews should be merely user-visible _representations_ of the model; you should not be _consulting_ them for anything, you should already _know_ what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that there is a tris in cells 00, 11, 22 and 02, 11,20 so change your for with further checks:

```kotlin
if (board[0][0].text!="" && board[1][1].text==board[0][0].text && board[2][2].text==board[0][0].text) {
    winner.setText("You win")
}
if (board[0][2].text!="" && board[1][1].text==board[0][2].text && board[2][0].text==board[0][2].text) {
    winner.setText("You win")
}
```

Finally, if one of the if is ok you can stop checking for the others since there's already a winner.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It's not that the anti-diagonal check is not working because I omitted the code for it. It's just that the diagonal check simply doesn't work. I don't think adding the condition for the anti-diagonal would change anything.

Comment: @downmath Please explain what "the diagonal check simply doesn't work" _means_. How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @downmath also how do we know you've gotten the ids right?

Comment: @matt It doesn't change the winner textView's text to "You win"

Comment: @downmath well, this is why you've got a debugger. What did it tell you? Does `winnerCheck` get called when you think it should be? If so, watch the logic step by step; is it doing what you expect it to do on every line?